# Calculating change between duplicate rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have data that is exported from a third party program. The data is always in the form of a range and always a fresh unsaved excel file every time it's exported.

The data essentially contains this type of format.

```
169 31.0
169 29.0
12 01.31
03 22.0
12 1.09
03 21.5
```

Sorry I am new at this website. Essentially one column is a code associated with ingredients, and the second column is their weights. You're going to see duplicates as the bakery is weight them before and after. I would like to have to calculate to see how much of each ingredient is used. So the final output would be a table with a list of unique ingredient codes in one column and difference between the before and after in the other column.

I have tried using a pivot table but that sums them up. The difference formula needs a separate column to compare itself against. I don't have that unfortunately.

Is there a simpler way to do this? I want essentially the same functionality of a pivot table but with difference instead of sum.

Comment: Provide a sample of your table with a few records along with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data are in columns A to B and start from row 1, you could try this code:

```
Sub Main2()
    Dim cell As Range

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Cells
            If .Exists(cell.Value) Then
                .Item(cell.Value) = .Item(cell.Value) - cell.Offset(, 1).Value
            Else
                .Item(cell.Value) = cell.Offset(1).Value
            End If
        Next cell
        Range("C1").Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
        Range("D1").Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Items)
    End With
End Sub
```

that outputs in columns C and D